# Conversion from CSS to UserScript

Tags: css, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts, userstyles

I'm trying to convert a small piece of UserStyles visual theme code into a TamperMonkey script. Until a few months ago, UserStyles.org had a feature that allowed you to do this with the click of a button. Alas, it is no longer available.

Please help me convert the following CSS code to UserScript :

```
/* ==UserStyle==
@name         Remove Youtube left sidebar
@description  Makes YouTube sidebar collapse
@author       fgtranime
@license      No License
==/UserStyle== */

@-moz-document domain("youtube.com") {
#guide {
    display: none;
}

ytd-app[guide-persistent-and-visible] ytd-page-manager.ytd-app {
    margin-left: 0;
}
}
```

p.s. I have tried using several converters found on GitHub, but none of them gives the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a userscript based on your userStyle

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Remove Youtube left sidebar
// @description   Makes YouTube sidebar collapse
// @match         *://*.youtube.com/*
// @version       1.0
// @grant         GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

const css = 
`#guide {
  display: none;
}

ytd-app[guide-persistent-and-visible] ytd-page-manager.ytd-app {
  margin-left: 0;
}`;

GM_addStyle(css);
```